# Java Compilation Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError:

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm getting this error when i run my code not sure what is wrong here:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: first3weeks/Main, method: <init> signature: ()V) Constructor must call super() or this()
Java Result: 1
```

Student Code:

```
package first3weeks;   

public class Student {
    private String name, id;
    private int[] score = new int[3];


    public Student(){}

    public Student(String stName, String stID, int stScore[]){
        name = stName;
        id = stID;
        score = stScore;
    }

    public void setName(String nameIn){
        name = nameIn;
    }

    public void setID(String idIn){
        id = idIn;
    }

    public void setScore(int scoreIn[]){
        score = scoreIn;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getID(){
        return id;
    }

    public int[] getScore(){
        return score;
    }

    public double avScore(){
        double total = score[1] + score[2] + score[3];
        return (total/3);
    }

    public void printOut(){
        System.out.println("Student Name: " + getName() + "\n" + "Student ID: " + getID() + "\n" + "Student Average: " + avScore());
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
package first3weeks;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] score1 = {12,15,19};
        int[] score2 = {32,65,29};
        Student stud1 = new Student("Rob", "001", score1);
        Student stud2 = new Student("Jeff", "002", score2);
        stud1.printOut();
        stud2.printOut();

        Student stud3 = new Student();
        int[] score3 = {56,18,3};
        stud3.setName("Richard");
        stud3.setID("003");
        stud3.setScore(score3);
        stud3.printOut();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is in the package first3weeks

Comment: java.lang.VerifyError occurs when you have inconsistency in your class file. Clean your project. Compile and run again!

Comment: I found the issue in the main class i had left a line break between some code and after removing it, that has fixed the error and its running fine now,
thanks for the contributions :)

Comment: @rob1994 that was definitely not the real cause. Aniket is correct.

Comment: well removing the line stopped the error

Answer (score 2):

This error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: first3weeks/Main, 
    method: <init> signature: ()V) Constructor must call super() or this()
```

means the byte code has not been generated correctly.  This could be a bug in the compiler.  I would make sure you have the latest update of either Java 7 update 40 or Java 6 update 45.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code using version `1.7.0_17` of java and the only exception i am getting is a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3`.**

In java, Array is zero-based index, i.e first element has zero index, so in the method `avScore` you should do:

```
 public double avScore(){
       double total = score[0] + score[1] + score[2];
       return (total/3);
 }
```

Comment: Although it is a mistake it has nothing to do with the error OP is getting. Also that function is never called.

Comment: @AniketThakur The `avScore` method is called by `printOut`.

Comment: Did not see it. Apologies for that but the problem OP is facing is different and is mostly due to inconsistency in the class file. Although he also needs to fix problem you pointed out.